# mysql - table transpose / pivot

Tags: mysql

Should be not that complicated I guess - but I am kind of beginner level - sorry for that

How can I transform / pivot the table into the result table?
So that the one column ls will be split in 2 columns -> long and short seperated.

[here the example of the table and the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkilH.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can use query below as a basic and calculate net_ls and price columns as required.

```
select p.login, p.symbol,
    max(case when p.ls = 'long' then size end) long,
    max(case when p.ls = 'short' then size end) short,
    max(case when p.ls = 'long' then price end) longPrice,
    max(case when p.ls = 'short' then price end) shortPrice
from positions p
group by p.log_in, p.symbol
```